# How to get a trace of function calls in flutter code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Is there something in Android Studio, or DART VM Observatory, that would allow me to get a view into to the history of methods called?

Something that looks like this:

```
main()
    - myApp()
        - fun1()
            - fun2()
                -fun3()
            - fun4()
        - fun2()
            - fun3()
```

etc.,

Oh, I would also like to save or cut/paste this stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4934#issuecomment-233073279

> The observatory timeline exposes tracing, there also used to be a flutter trace command which could be used to start/stop tracing it may still work.

I haven't tried either myself, just stumbled upon this issue.